# Perfect tense replacement for "supposed to"

Tags: expressions

So I heard that one cant or perhaps shouldnt,not entirely sure, use this in perfect and past perfect tense so I am looking for something that exprsses similar meaning.

Comment: Could you please give an example, do you mean "had supposed"?

Comment: He had been supposed to help him. Apparently sounds bad.

Comment: Yes, that would usually be phrased "he was supposed to help him".  However, "I had supposed that would happen." meaning "I had thought that that would happen." is possible.